# Tensorflow CNN cost stops improving

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to develop a small network for the aerial cactus identification challenge.

This is a binary classification challenge (0 no cactus, 1 is cactus), but my networks is always outputting the same cost.
I built a simple network, which works when implemented with keras, but I'm trying to use tensorflow training loop for learning purposes, but can't make it work

My network architecture:

```
2 Conv 64x3 + Maxpooling

2 Conv 128x3 + Maxpooling

Flatten

Dense 1024

Dense 512

Dense 1
```

Here is my code:

```py
def process_one_batch(x, y):
    inputs = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu')(x)
    inputs = Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu')(inputs)
    inputs = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)(inputs)

    inputs = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu')(inputs)
    inputs = Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu')(inputs)
    inputs = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2)(inputs)

    flat = Flatten()(block2)

    dense1 = Dense(1024, activation="relu")(flat)
    dense2 = Dense(512, activation="relu")(dense1)

    dense2 = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(dense2)

    res = dense2
    return res

NB_EPOCHS = 5
def create_dataset(X, y, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, nb_epochs=NB_EPOCHS, batch=True):
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((X, y))
    dataset = dataset.map(my_process_path)
    if batch:
        dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size)
    dataset = dataset.repeat(nb_epochs)
    dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=2)
    iterator =  tf.data.make_one_shot_iterator(dataset)
    #iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    next_element = iterator.get_next()
    y_ = process_one_batch(next_element[0], next_element[1])
    return dataset, next_element, y_

train_ds, (train_x, train_y), prediction = create_dataset(X_train.values, y_train.values)
test_ds, (test_x, test_y), test_prediction = create_dataset(X_test.values, y_test.values, batch=True)

cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(
            train_y, tf.reshape(tf.transpose(prediction), [-1]), from_logits=True
))
optimiser = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=0.001).minimize(cross_entropy)
init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    train_steps = int(len(X_train.values) / BATCH_SIZE)
    val_steps = int(len(X_test.values) / BATCH_SIZE)
    # initialise the variables
    sess.run(init_op)
    print('Init')
    for epoch in range(NB_EPOCHS):
        avg_cost = 0
        train_acc = 0
        for i in range(train_steps):
            _, c, ac = sess.run([optimiser, cross_entropy, accuracy_train])
            print(c)
            avg_cost += 1
            train_acc += ac
        print('train_acc: ', train_acc/train_steps)
        print(train_steps, val_steps)
        print("Epoch:", (epoch + 1), "cost =", "{:.3f}".format(avg_cost / train_steps))
    print("\nTraining complete!")
```

I have tried debugging the model input, it's not always the same, but after the 3rd batch cost is stucked at 0.6931472. Just after I run a simple keras model on the dataset and everything works fine, so I don't thinks it's a data related problem

Any idea would be gladly appreciated

Comment: I think it should be `avg_cost += c` instead of `avg_cost += 1`